# Specify multiple targets to the django migration command

Tags: python, django, database, django-migrations

I am planning to load a bunch of data from elsewhere another environment into my development database. The problem is that the data source is not necessarily from the most recent version. I have a list of apps:migration_levels, that I can migrate too. But there does not seem to be a good way give the migration command multiple targets. how can I do somthing like this:

```
./manage.py migrate postapp:0020 commentapp:0015 userapp:0008
```

We tried looping and doing one app at a time, but ran into problems with cross dependencies.

If there is a library that provides a version of this command, that would also be a valid answer.